# wcsrtombs returns (size_t) -1

Tags: c, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert from a string of type `wchar_t*` to `char`, but for some reason having trouble making it work. I have successfully done the opposite (from `char` to `wchar_t*`) with `mbsrtowcs()`, but this defeats me. The return value section in`man 3 wcsrtombs` has this:

> The wcsrtombs() function returns the number of bytes that make up the
>          converted part of multibyte sequence, not including the terminating
>          null byte.  If a wide character was encountered which could not be
>          converted, (size_t) -1 is returned, and errno set to EILSEQ.

Consider this minimal example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>

char *convert_to_multibyte(const wchar_t* arg, long num_chars) {

        size_t buffer_size = num_chars * sizeof(wchar_t);
        char *mb = malloc(buffer_size); // will waste some memory though

        mbstate_t state;
        wcsrtombs(NULL, &arg, 0, &state); // this supposedly will initialize the mbstate_t struct

        size_t result;
        result = wcsrtombs(mb, &arg, buffer_size, &state);
        if (result == (size_t)-1) {
                free(mb);
                return NULL;
        }

        mb[buffer_size-1] = '\0';

        return mb;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "fi_FI.UTF-8");

        wchar_t test[] = L"ÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖ";

        char *converted = convert_to_multibyte(test, wcslen(test));
//      printf("%s\n", converted);

        return 0;
}
```

With the test string `L"ÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖ"`, `(size_t) -1` is returned, which implies an inconvertible wide char was encountered - this doesn't happen with a string that doesn't have any non-ASCII characters. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsrtombs/ may be able to help you

Comment: For your code the OS is of interest, because you try to set an UTF-8 locale, which doesn't exist in Windows. Why not just `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`. Much more portable.

Comment: Main (or another) problem seems to be that you don't initialize the state. In C++ you could just add an `= {}` to the declaration. I guess in C maybe you have to call `memset` or someting.

Comment: I'm on Linux, but `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` still fixed the problem! Why is that?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe it didn't like the Finnish locale? But `""` gives you whatever the local natural locale is.

Comment: Apparently.. I've heard many times that the world of character encoding is a mess, but it's starting to dawn on me on quite a different level :D

Comment: You selected utf8, it is not a multibyte encoding.  It is a Unicode encoding.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'd guess there is some limited context where UTF-8 is not regarded as a multibyte encoding. One such is Windows, but that's not the OP's OS. What are you thinking of specifically? See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Compared_to_other_multi-byte_encodings). The Wikipedia editors would have to change the title of that section if you were right in general.